# Unable to detect Zebra DS457 scanner through scanner SDK

Tags: c#, windows, sdk, barcode-scanner, zebra-printers

I am developing a windows forms application, for Zebra DS457 scanner using its SDK for Windows in C#. The api calls execute with no error or exception but unable to detect a scanner which connected to the PC using serial to USB moxa switch. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: How can you think that someone would be able to help you without any details or code?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Maybe it needs a driver installed? I worked with Zebra printers and scanners, and I think I needed to install the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, it is possible that the scanner hardware is set to HID keyboard emulation mode.

It is suggested that the scanner must be in OPOS or SNAPI communication mode around 1:58 of the video tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rN5M6ATO708&list=PLrcZVTwQp0lesloWgP3gReIZZqst5Hb-z&index=8

You should be able to change the mode with a setting bar code etc.